# Is there a way to detects all the Prob devices in Device Manager, either in C# or Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there a way to detect all the Problem devices in Device Manager, either in C# or Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315379.aspx) and its [Win32_PnPEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx) class to retrieve the devices installed on your computer and their status. Your query would ressemble this:

```
$computer = "LocalHost" 
$namespace = "root\CIMV2" 
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PnPEntity -computername $computer -namespace $namespace
```

Depending on your exact requirements, you can filter on the Availability, Status or ConfigManagerErrorCode fields. Without knowing what your "problem" really is, it's not possible to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you Thanks allot @David Brabant.
Actually i wanted a PowerShell script that detects all problem devices in Device Manager.

Required output format:
DeviceName  BeforeStatusCode  AfterStatusCode   Fixed/Not Fixed

Speaker         22                 0              Fixed

Comment: @AB_Soft It doesn't appear that the BeforeStatusCode is available. You *can* get items with issues by piping that to `Where{$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -gt 0} | FT Name, ConfigManagerErrorCode,Status` and that will show you anything with an error code. Or `Where{$_.Status -ne "OK" -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Status)}` will give you everything that is not OK (including Degraded with no error code).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks, that `[string]::...` thing was indeed the secret in the sauce. I could not find a way to use ` -eq ""` (i.e. a Null string).